# char** equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c++, pointers

I am converting a C++ project into Java. I have one doubt, what is the equivalent of `char**` in Java, is it `String[]` or `String[][]`?

Comment: That depends on the semantics of the `char**`. Does it point to an array or a single `char*`? Does the pointer(s) it points to, point to single `char`s or `char` arrays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char[][]` or `String[]`.
Depends on context

Comment: Also, reagarding the context, have in mind that Java [strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are immutable.

Comment: Exactly - that's one of the toughest aspects of C/C++ - you can't definitively explain what a pointer declaration is from the declaration alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really express the meaning of `char**` in Java so there's no equivalent, but if that's actually a pointer to the first element of an array of zero-terminated C-strings, then `String[]` is as close as you can get.

If it's a two-dimensional "pseudo-array" of `char`, then `char[][]` is close enough.

If it's neither but just a pointer to a pointer, then there's no equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

I would say String[] if I remember correctly. String is a handle and that would be an array of handles.